# Statically stored set of strings

Tags: c++, c++20, stdstring

I have some string comparison logic in my program, e.g:

```cpp
std::unordered_set<std::string> relational_operators{
    "==",
    "!=",
    ">",
    "<",
    ">=",
    "<="
};

bool is_relational(std::string token) {
  relational_operators.contains(token);
}

if (is_relational(token)) {
  // ...do stuff
}
```

All values of set are known at compile time, but checks will be done on user input.
How such strings are usually stored in c++? I don't know if storing a set like this is a good idea, probably not because it can possibly throw an error when allocation happens (IDE warnings).

So for example if i had another set of strings (supported operators):

```cpp
std::unordered_set<std::string> supported_operators {
  // ...
};
```

Support for new operators will be added over time. So i just want to add a new operator to a set. So basically i want to avoid situation like this:

```cpp
bool is_supported_op(std::string token) {
  return token == "<" || token == ">" || token == "!="; // ... many more ||
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with static storage duration warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938090/how-to-deal-with-static-storage-duration-warnings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give that you're apparently not planning to modify the set of strings at run-time, I'd probably use an `std::array<std::string, N>` to hold them, then use `std::binary_search` to do the search.

From a theoretical viewpoint, you get O(log N) lookups either way--but in reality, the array is likely to give enough better cache locality to improve performance quite a bit (especially if you're using a modern implementation of `std::string` that implements the short string optimization).

Comment: `std::binary_search` needs a sorted array, so do we need to manually keep the array sorted?

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin: You could either keep it sorted manually, or use a call to `std::sort` during initialization. I'd usually prefer the latter--more proof against boneheaded programmers (of which I'm often one). Theoretically wastes some time during startup, but given the number of items likely to be involved, not enough to notice.

Comment: @康桓瑋: Yes, as long as you're sure it'll be small, `find` should be fine--but part of the question says "many more"--which might mean a dozen or might mean hundreds. If it's dozens, go with `find`. If it's hundreds or thousands, `binary_search` is probably better.

Comment: If performance becomes critical, you can likely apply perfect hashing - statically generate a hash function and a lookup table, generating a .cpp file on the fly. It could also make sense to determine the maximum length, and skip a lookup for entries that are too long. (especially here, where operators are probably no longer than 3 characters and likely mixed with longer identifiers)

Comment: @MSalters There exists a repo https://github.com/serge-sans-paille/frozen, to get constexpr unordered_map